# How to count the number of filled columns in an array

Tags: java

I have an String array  say

```
                    String str = new String [5];

                     str[0] = "Europe";

                     str[1]= "America";
```

How I can return the number of   filled  columns in my array?

Comment: Iterate over the array and count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not assign any value to the empty elements you can count `null`.

```
int count=0;
for(final String s : str) {
   if(s != null) ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache common lang's isBlank](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29) to check the same.

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(str[i]) {
  ++count;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you your answer might be my gate to apache

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun if you're going to explore adding 3rd party libraries then I would certainly look into Guava rather than Apache Commons.